# Error: 'some' types are only implemented for the declared type of properties and subscripts and the return type of functions

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have the following code in playground (Xcode 13.0):

```
protocol Summable {
    static func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}

extension Int: Summable {}
extension Double: Summable {}
extension String: Summable {}

struct Print {    
    func printSummable(x: some Summable) {
        print(x)
    }
}
```

But I am getting the error

> 'some' types are only implemented for the declared type of properties
> and subscripts and the return type of functions

I want to print only the objects that conform to Summable. Do "some"/"any" keywords only work on protocols with associated types?

Comment: Just remove the keyword `some` - All you need to declare is that `x` conforms to `Summable` - `func printSummable(x: Summable)`

Comment: @Paulw11 I removed the `some` and I got the error: `Protocol 'Summable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements`

Answer (score 0):

It works on Swift version 5.7.1. I had to update my xcode :)

Comment: @matt typo. Fixed :) Thanks!